# Remove value change listener

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I am facing problem in value change listener.

I have added value change listener in vaadin option group which has six checkboxes.

```
optionGroup.addValueChangeListener(this :: optionGroupValueChanged);
//..
private void optionGroupValueChanged(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
 //...
}
```

Now I have one another checkbox which selects all the checkboxes of the option group (because it's multiselect). I want to avoid call of value change listener for individual checkboxes so that I first removed the value change listener and added after selecting all as stated below.

```
selectAllCheckBox.addValueChangeListener(this :: selectAllChecked);
//...
private void selectAllChecked(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    final boolean isChecked = (boolean) valueChangeEvent.getProperty().getValue();
    //Following line does not remove the value change listener
    optionGroup.removeValueChangeListener(this :: optionGroupValueChanged);
    if(isChecked) {
        //So here it will call value change of option group six time
        optionGroup.getItemIds().stream().forEach( itemId -> optionGroup.select(itemId));
    } else {
        optionGroup.setValue(null);
    }
    optionGroup.addValueChangeListener(this :: optionGroupValueChanged);
}
```

I have checked code of vaadin `removeValueChangeListener` method it contains `markAsDirty();` method. What is the reason of this behavior ? Is there any other alternative solution for my problem ?

*Note : Version of vaadin is 7.5.0*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `this :: optionGroupValueChanged` creates each time new instance of `ValueChangeListener`. You don't want this, you want to remove very specific instance of `ValueChangeListener`. The solution is to remember (in private field in example) the reference to the listener and pass it in your add and remove ValueChangeListener calls.

```
optionGroupListener = this :: optionGroupValueChanged;
optionGroup.addValueChangeListener(optionGroupListener);

private void selectAllChecked(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    final boolean isChecked = (boolean) valueChangeEvent.getProperty().getValue();
    //change here
    optionGroup.removeValueChangeListener(optionGroupListener );
    if(isChecked) {
        optionGroup.getItemIds().stream().forEach( itemId -> optionGroup.select(itemId));
    } else {
        optionGroup.setValue(null);
    }
//and here
    optionGroup.addValueChangeListener(optionGroupListener );
}
```